# passing to touchesEnded:withEvent:

Tags: ios, xcode

Dumb question, but can you pass anything touchesEnded.  I wanted to pass UIImageView piece to it.  I'm new to this.  I know that NSSet is a subclass of NSObject so i was thinking that there is a way that i can pass my UIImageView through the NSSet somehow.

```
-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{

    if (!isTouchingEmptyField) {

        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];

        piece.center = CGPointMake(48, 366); 

        [UIView commitAnimations]; 
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you know which view you want to pass in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do that, but I wouldn't.

I would use a UIGestureRecognizer on the particular UIViews you want to add the behavior to with a selector that performs that exact action.